# How can I create a CSV document in the Shift_JIS character set?

Tags: php, csv, character-encoding, shift-jis

I can manaully force a CSV file to be detected as UTF-8 by adding a BOM, like so:

```
file_put_contents($filename, "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $csv);
```

Is there a similar thing I can do to force a CSV file to be detected as Shift_JIS?

Comment: You're making sure to actually write data to the file in the Shift_JIS character set, right?

Comment: Yes, I export to UTF-8 is ok. Now, I want change to  Shift_JIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shift JIS does not have an equivalent "content type marker" like the BOM. If you output a CSV encoded in Shift JIS, whoever will read that file will have to know it's in Shift JIS or otherwise detect the encoding.

To create a Shift JIS encoded file, just make sure your `$csv` data is Shift JIS encoded. Convert using `iconv` or `mb_convert_encoding` if necessary.

Comment: i use mb_convert_encoding($csv," Shift-JIS","UTF-8"); but i open file It stills is format ANSI as UTF-8.

Comment: Do you mean your text editor *thinks* it's ANSI encoded or is it actually ANSI encoded? Again, there's no magic marker for Shift JIS, you probably need to *tell* your editor what encoding it should open the file in, if it doesn't detect it itself.

Comment: No, it's not the same. Do you see the correct characters, or do you see gobbledegook? If the former, your document is not actually Shift JIS encoded. If the latter, the document is Shift JIS encoded and Notepad++ is too daft to realize it. Again, *choose "Shift JIS" when you open the file* to tell Notepad++ the file is encoded in Shift JIS. I don't know Notepad++, can't tell you how to do that. Maybe read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).

Comment: @mum you can find Shift-Jis in `Notepad++` in `Encoding -> Character sets -> Japanese -> Shift-Jis`